# Is it possible to load the og:image and page title of another website on my website using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I own the website `mywebsite.com`.

The source code of `domain.com/something.php?some=42` (not my website) is

```
<title>OtherSite - TEXT I WANT</title>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://image-i-want.com/image.png" />
```

Is it possible for me using javascript to go to `domain.com/something.php?some=42`, grab the `TEXT I WANT` AND `https://image-i-want.com/image.png` and place them in the code below respectively?

```
<div>
    <img id="other-site-img" src="">
</div>
<div>
    <span id="other-site-text"></span>
</div>
```

So it would look like:

```
<div>
    <img id="other-site-img" src="https://image-i-want.com/image.png">
</div>
<div>
    <span id="other-site-text">TEXT I WANT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What have you researched and tried so far?

Comment: @Zak I have simply tried `var name = "";$.get('domain.com/something.php?some=42', function(response) {  console.log(response);});` but I get the response `from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depend of the CORS policy of the target domain.

If the server allow CORS, you can do a `$.ajax` and parse the DOM to get the values.
If the server deny CORS, you can't do it in JavaScript.

Comment: CORS only applies to sending and receiving data to from other websites on different domain ..   What the OP is asking is entirely possible, since the HTML of the page is public domain (for the most part)

Comment: Yes, many website allow CORS to there HTML (but not all), but since `mywebsite.com` is different of `domain.com`, he may encounter the same problem as I've already faced few times ago.

Comment: @Zak what are you talking about? What's the "public domain for the most part"?

Comment: Is there anyway to get around CORS while keeping the web scrap client side?

Comment: It's not possible. As @keidakida say, you will need to do it on the "server-side" (or node, or anything else than the browser).

Comment: @James yes, using things like cURL or any server-side reader. You could either read the website and pass its HTML to your client-side for parsing, or parse it on the server-side too.

Comment: @Bazaim The thing is I don't want to use my server side capacity to do it.. So I thought it may be possible using javascript

Comment: @RoboRobok I understand I can do it server-side without issues, but I wanted to do it client side

Comment: If you want to do it without any bridge, your only possibility is to ask the owners of that website to enable CORS. But you understand that while doing it server-side you can still achieve the same user experience? You'd just `fetch()` to your own server-side script and still get that result without redirection. It's either this or that, no way to `fetch()` without permission.

Comment: @RoboRobok The issue becomes this. Each time a user visits my website I need to grab 10 texts/images (all on `domain.com` but different pages on the site hence different texts and images). If I have 200 users on my site at one time, it means I need to visit `domain.com` `10 * 200 = 2000` times. Visiting the site this much will make the site think I am a spammer or a robot if my IP is always the same. I could use proxies but that will drastically slow down the page loading of my website. I could cache and store the text and images, but there are millions of pages on `domain.com`.

Comment: @RoboRobok continued... And every day millions of pages are added. Indexing these pages before hand could be an option, but I wouldn't be able to keep up with `domain.com` Is there a better solution?

Comment: But with `fetch()` they'd be spammed as well, wouldn't they? I think you should make a server-side bridge, which would also do the caching. Is this website okay with having so many requests from you?

Answer (score 0):

If that `domain.com/something.php` allows [Cross-Site](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) request Then you can do it using JavaScript. Else you have to use WebScraping to access the data using Python or PHP or anything else